# how do I get my drop down list to show the selected item in setState

Tags: flutter, dart

this drop-down list will get its items from the future builder 
but after I choose an item from the list it doesn't change the ​selected item, I believe it's because I didn't use the regular string or int items

```
FutureBuilder(
  future: getCategories(http.Client()),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Categories>> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

    selectedCategory = snapshot.data[0].id; 

    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      this.categoriesList = snapshot.data;
      if (this.categoriesList.length > 0) {
        return DropdownButton<int>(
          value:  selectedCategory,
          onChanged: (int newValue) {
            setState(() {
              selectedCategory = newValue;
              this.eventOpj.categoryId = newValue;
            });
          },
          items: snapshot.data
                         .map<DropdownMenuItem<int>>((Categories catg) {
                           return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                             value: catg.id,
                             child: Text(catg.nameEn),
                           );
                         }).toList(),
        );
      } else {
        return Text('data');
      }
    }
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have your logic *in* your build method.

```
selectedCategory=snapshot.data[0].id;
```

Keep the logic out of the build method and if you need to apply logic on receiving data this should be called within a stateful widget's initState.

Comment: i removed it outside and every time i select i got this error : Failed assertion: line 620 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null || items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value == value).length == 1': is not true.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the future call just once in the `initState()`, setting the future to a `_future` variable and then use that variable on the `FutureBuilder`, something like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _future = getCategories(http.Client());
}

FutureBuilder(
  future: _future,
  ...
```

Also the line `selectedCategory = snapshot.data[0].id;` should be done only the first time you load the results, since is just to select the first element of the `DropdownButton`. You could put that line inside an `if (selectedCategory == null)`